# Where can I find Oracle Admin client download link for version 11.2.0.3

Tags: oracle, client

I was trying to download oracle admin client for 11.2.0.3 ,however only 11.2.0.1 version is available.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win64soft-094461.html

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: not sure what an 'admin' client is, but if you just need connectivity, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 12c, Oracle made only the base releases publicly avialable on OTN, to download patch set releases, you needed to have a valid licence and support contract.
If you have a valid licence and support contract, you can still download 11.2.0.3 from https://support.oracle.com

Or using this link:

https://updates.oracle.com/Orion/Services/download/p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip?aru=14255124&patch_file=p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip

The file you are looking for is:

```
p10404530_112030_MSWIN-x86-64_4of7.zip
```